# Browser doesn't set cookies an send in header

Tags: vue.js, session, cookies, jwt, nestjs

I have a nest js server that run on localhost 3000 and I use vuejs on http://127.0.0.1 on port 5173

I have a function that authenticated the user in my auth.controller.js

```js
@Post('auth/login')
  async login(
    @Body() payload: { email: string; password: string },
    @Req() req,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) res,
  ) {
    
    const user = await this.authService.login(payload.email);

       const ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://127.0.0.1:5173', 'http://postman'];
    if (ALLOWED_ORIGINS.indexOf(req.headers.origin) > -1) {
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS');
    }
   
    res
      .cookie('sessionId', user.jwtToken, {
        // secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? false : true, //set true in production
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1 * 60 * 60 * 2 * 1000,
        sameSite: 'none', //Should be "strict" in prod
        signed: true,
      })
      .send({
        message: 'Token contenu dans le xsrf',
        xsrfToken: user.token.xsrfToken,
      });
    // console.log(req.cookies);
  }
```

As you can see I return the cookie in the res and I can see the cookie in the network part of the browser

[image]

But when I make axios request in the front with the option withCredentials set to true, I don't have the cookie inside the header.

There is my request in front

```js
const apiClientWithCredential = axios.create({
  withCredentials:true,
  baseURL : "http://localhost:3000"
})
```

```js
getUsers(email: string, password: string) {
    return apiClientWithCredential.post(`/auth/login`, {
      email,
      password
    })
  },
  getProtected() {
    return apiClientWithCredential.get(`http://localhost:3000/protected`, {
      headers: {
        'x-xsrf-token': `${window.sessionStorage['x-xsrf-token']}`
      }
    })
  },
```

In postman I correctly received the cookie d I can it set it automatically in other request.

[image]

Any Idea on why the browser cant automatically send the cookie in request header?

Comment: I refreshed the browser and I clean all cookies and now it works !!